# How to check a table exists in sqlite3 or not

Tags: python-2.7, sqlite

I am new to SQL. I want to check that a table exist in data base or not. If it does not exist than create it. Also I want to check that a record exist in table or not. If exists than update it with new data, If does not exist than insert a new record in table. Here is the code. I don't know how to check for a existing table,record.

```
  import sqlite3 as lite            
  con = lite.connect('test.db')

        cur = con.cursor()    

        con.execute('''CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE 
                   (ITEMA            TEXT PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL,
                   ITEMB           CHAR(50)                 NOT NULL,                       
                   ITEMC        CHAR(50),
                   ITEM0         TEXT
                   ITEM1           TEXT
                   ITEM2           TEXT
                   ITEM3           TEXT
                   ITEM4           TEXT);''')



        con.execute("INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE (ID,NAME,ADDRESS,MOBILE_NUMBER,TRANSPORT_FOR_LUNCH,ONLY_DROP,KIDS,ADULTS) \
        VALUES   (%s,%s',%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)" %(ia,ib,ic,i0,i1,i2,i3,i4));
```

Comment: the column names of your **CREATE TABLE** and your **INSERT INTO** statements do not match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test for table existence in sqlite, you can do something like:

```
   cursor = con.cursor()
   statement = "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';"
   if (table_name,) in cursor.execute(statement).fetchall():
        print "Table %s exists." % table_name
```

To update or create depending upon pre-existence of a record, sqlite allows the use of [replace](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_replace.html), which is an alias for `insert or replace`:

```
  replace into table_name (columns) values (values)
```

Comment: Instead of INSERT when I use REPLACE in above code. I get below error. Error no such column: A000000:

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE IF NOT EXISTS ..
```

creates only if it does not exist